# Javascript: how to create nested DIVs starting from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, domdocument

Probably it is easy, but not for me.
Starting from a JSON tree structure, I'm trying to iterate it, and creating a DIV for each node, nest the DIVs and, for example, change the background color of each DIV, taking the information from the JSON object.
What I've done till now is this fnction:

```
function uiCreator(tree, page, container){
function iterator (obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[i] === "object" && obj[i] !== null) {
            page.Render("createElement", "D"+i, "DIV"); //page.Render() wrap the DOM functions and saves the DOM objects inside an array
            page.Render("createTextNode", "T"+i, i);
            page.Render("appendChild", "D"+i, "T"+i); //appends the text node inside the DIV
            page.Render("appendChild", container, "D"+i); //appends (or it should) the DIV to the upper level.
            page.Render("margin", "D"+i, "10px");
            page.Render("border", "D"+i, "solid");
            page.Render("backgroundColor", "D"+i, obj[i].color);
            if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") container = "D"+i; // if the first child of obj[i] is an object, container is updated
            iterator(obj[i]);
            if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") container = "D"+i;
        }
    }
}
iterator(tree);
```

}

Where "tree" is the JSON data structure, "page" is an object to manipulate the DOM (it wraps the DOM functions and store the reference in an associative array), and "container" is used as reference to an external DIV which will contain the results of the function (during the iterations "container" is updated to reference the current node of the sctructure).
Right now this function works fine going down with the structure levels. But not when is time to go back. The function iterates the entire structure in the right way, I think the problem is here:

```
page.Render("appendChild", container, "D"+i);
```

and here:

```
if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") container = "D"+i;
```

Thank you!

PS:
An example of the used tree structure:

```
treeObj = {
"01" : {
    "01_01" : {
        "01_01_01" : {"color" : "#F0F8FF"},
        "01_01_02" : {"color" : "#FAEBD7"},
        "01_01_03" : {"color" : "#00FFFF"},
        "01_01_04" : {"color" : "#7FFFD4"},
        "01_01_05" : {"color" : "#F0FFFF"},
        "color" : "#7CFC00"
    },
    "01_02" : {
        "01_02_01" : {"color" : "#F5F5DC"},
        "01_02_02" : {"color" : "#FFE4C4"},
        "01_02_03" : {"color" : "#000000"},
        "01_02_04" : {"color" : "#FFEBCD"},
        "01_02_05" : {"color" : "#0000FF"},
        "color" : "#FFFACD"
    }, ...
```

Comment: What is the issue here ? I mean what works and what doesn't ? I don't follow  *But not when is time to go back.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for my explanation. The problem is that the function does not nest the DIVs in the correct hierarchy. Taking "treeObj" as example, the function creates a DIV for the node "01", inside it creates a div for the node "01_01" and inside it creates the divs for the nodes from "01_01_01" to "01_01_05" the error comes when it create the div for the node "01_02" because it appends this node under "01_01" and not under "01".

Comment: Hey no probs. you have it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure to have understood how exactly, but it seems to work properly now. Here the new version of the function:

```
function uiCreator(tree, page, container){
    var iter = 1;
    var iarr = [container];
    function jsonIterator(obj, iter) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[i] === "object" && obj[i] !== null) {
                page.Render("createElement", "D"+i, "DIV");
                page.Render("border", "D"+i, "solid");
                page.Render("createTextNode", "T"+i, i);
                iarr[iter] = "D"+i;
                page.Render("appendChild", "D"+i, "T"+i);
                page.Render("appendChild", iarr[iter-1], "D"+i);
                page.Render("margin", "D"+i, "10px");
                page.Render("backgroundColor", "D"+i, obj[i].color);
                if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") iter++;
                jsonIterator(obj[i], iter);
                if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") iter--;
            }
        }
    }
    jsonIterator(tree, iter);
}
```

I've added a counter for the recursive iterations:

```
var iter = 1;
```

And an array to store all the Object Keys:

```
var iarr = [container];
```

With `iarr[iter] = "D"+i;` I have always the correct upper level to use:

```
page.Render("appendChild", iarr[iter-1], "D"+i);
```

And last but not the least, with this code:

```
if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") iter++;
jsonIterator(obj[i], iter);
if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object") iter--;
```

I can manage the recursion, and I increase or decrease the counter.
I hope this can be useful for someone, and anyone who has a better idea to implement this function, is welcome!

Comment: EDIT:
in this new version the instruction:
if(typeof obj[i][Object.keys(obj[i])[0]] === "object"); is no more needed.